# Conditional jQuery statement to check if text of <li> already in <ul>?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, contains

I have a div that contains a dynamically generated list where items are added on click.

I'd like to add a conditional statement along the lines of:

> "If this item is not in the list,
>    do something,
>    else,
>    do something else"

This is what I have got so far, I think the selector in the conditional statement may be incorrect as the desired functionality is not working (no errors in Firebug though):

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){ 
    $("span.tooltip").hover(function() {
        link = $(this).attr("data-link");
    });

    $("span.tooltip").click(function() {
        link_text = $(this).text();

        // my conditional statement with issues
        if ($('.area_one ul li').not(":contains(link_test)")) {
            $(".area_one ul").prepend("<li>" + link + "</li>");
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Dynamically Populated List**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link one</a><span class="clearMe" style="display: none;">clear</span></li>
<li><a href="#">link two</a><span class="clearMe" style="display: none;">clear</span></li>
<li><a href="#">link three</a><span class="clearMe" style="display: none;">clear</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
$("span.tooltip").click(function() {
  link_text = $(this).text();
  if ($(".area_one ul li:contains('"+link_text+"')").length == 0) { 
    $(".area_one ul").prepend("<li>" + link_text + "</li>");
  } else {
     alert("already present");
  }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d5pw/1/